# getting nth element with lxml/XPath fails

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

This might be a very simple thing, but I have continued to fail it.

When `root` contains one or more "<link />"s , root.xpath('(//link)') returns them all. But root.xpath('(//link)[0]') returns an empty list. What is wrong?

```
from unittest import TestCase, TestProgram

class T(TestCase):
    base_path = r'(//_:link)'
    def test0ok(self):
        self._test(2, self.base_path)
    def test1ng(self):
        self._test(1, self.base_path + r'[0]')
    def _test(self, expected, path):
        try:
            from lxml.etree import fromstring as parse_xml_string
        except ImportError:
            raise
        root = parse_xml_string(_xhtml)
        nsmap = dict(_=root.nsmap[None])
        gotten = root.xpath(path, namespaces=nsmap)
        gotten = len(gotten)
        self.assertEqual(expected, gotten)

_xhtml = br'''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
    "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"
>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<link rev="made" href="./" />
<link rel="contents" href="./" />
<title>te</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>st</h1>
</body>
</html>
'''[1:]

if __name__ == r'__main__':
    TestProgram()
```

Answer (score 5):

That's because the *indexing in XPath starts with 1*, not 0:

```
root.xpath('(//link)[1]')
```

Or, you can also get the element by index in Python (0 based):

```
root.xpath('//link')[0]
```